# How to prevent duplicate entries but allow duplicates in one column MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MYSQL table that stores restaurant IDs to email address. Any given email address can have as many restaurant IDs added to it. for example:

| email VARCHAR(45) | restaurant-id VARCHAR(45) |

fakeemail@gmail.com | 12534134134135341 
fakeemail@gmail.com | 44341341341341343 
fakeemail@gmail.com | 65656542242434134 
supercool@gmail.com | 12534134134135341 
totallyreal@gma.com | 44341341341341343 
lolzzz123@gmail.com | 65656542242434134

I currently have no primary key set because both columns need to be able to have duplicate entires. What I am looking to prevent is the following duplicates:

fakeemail@gmail.com | 12534134134135341 
fakeemail@gmail.com | 12534134134135341 
fakeemail@gmail.com | 12534134134135341

^^ How can i prevent the above while still allowing both columns to have duplicates?

Comment: "I currently have no primary key set because both columns need to be able to have duplicate entires." There is no relation or logic in this afirmation. You can have duplicated entries with a primary key, also with a unique primary key autoincrement.

Comment: "A primary key must contain unique values. If the primary key consists of multiple columns, the combination of values in these columns must be unique." - https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-primary-key/

Comment: one thing is a "duplicated row" and another thing is a "duplicated entry"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
email,
restaurant-id
FROM 
your_table
GROUP BY 
email,
restaurant-id
```

Comment: Yes this works for selecting, but I am referring to ADDING entries. As far as I know, there is no GROUP BY for this. Do I need to do something with the UNIQUE tag somewhere?

Comment: @TTT Two questions: 1) You mean that if you already has the case, didn't insert it? 2) What about already duplicates?

Comment: This is a completely fresh database and table. I'm looking for a create table statement that will prevent duplicate rows while still allowing the values within each column to be duplicates. I will then handle the SQLError in my program when duplicates are inserted.

Comment: @TTT Then make 2 or 3 tables. One for uniques data, one for duplicates, using relations and primary keys, autoincrement unique IDs. You have to learn about normalize 1 to infinite

Comment: Of course there is a way to do what you want, but is wrong.
INSERT INTO table (fields)
values
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT fields_to_check FROM table WHERE field= 'value'
) LIMIT 1;

Comment: @TTT https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5DCnCzDb8g

Comment: Thank u, I appreciate u telling me the conventional and unconventional way to do this! Appreciate it :)

Comment: @TTT No problem, shame I can't explaint it here and my english is the worst, sorry. But I tried to understand your problem at least! :) Thanks for the mark!